# How to search a collection for every instance of a single keyword

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to search a collection for every instance of a keyword.  For example, I'd like to search a collection for every instance of the word "authenticated".  Below is what one of the documents looks like in the collection that contains the keyword:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55945938d28f9f3809002afc"
    },
    "TAGS": ".source.s_net",
    "SOURCEIP": "10.10.0.5",
    "SEQNUM": "11004",
    "PROGRAM": "Core",
    "PRIORITY": "info",
    "MESSAGE": "<pppoe-jjcutter>: authenticated",
    "LEGACY_MSGHDR": "Core ",
    "HOST_FROM": "10.10.0.5",
    "HOST": "10.10.0.5",
    "FACILITY": "syslog",
    "DATE": "Jul  1 14:18:48"
}
```

Comment: what you want to search, you want to search `authenticated` keyword  in `MESSAGE`?

Comment: MESSAGE is the key and authenticated is the value - the collection is "messages".  I want to search collection "messages" for the value "authenticated".

Answer (score 0):

Check my github https://github.com/parthaindia/CustomMongo,

getByCondition(String tableName, Map condition) ,call this method where you tableName is your collection name ,Map is the key-value.In your case map would be

Map condition =new HashMap();

condition.put("MESSAGE",": authenticated");//or whatever object

You would receive an Array List in Json format.Use Type Token to convert into Array List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard text index.
Test data

```
db.people.insert({name: "Martin", remarks: "great architector"})
db.people.insert({name: "John", remarks: "awesome SO user, great programmer"})
db.people.insert({name: "Tony The Great", remarks: "inventor"})
```

Wildcard Index

```
db.people.createIndex({"$**" : "text"})
```

Query

```
db.people.find({$text: {$search: "great"}})
```

You will get all 3 records.
[MongoDB documentation on wildcard indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in find as below :

```
db.messages.find({"MESSAGE":{"$regex":"(\\s|^)authenticated(\\s|$)"}})
```

Or if you want to find out exact match of `authenticated` values then used below query :

```
db.messages.find({"MESSAGE":"authenticated"})
```

Comment: Thanks yogesh!  Worked like a charm!  I've been working on this for 4 days.